# How to get typescript to evaluate different typing scenarios instead of intersecting them?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Considering the code:

```
enum ActionName {
  BUMP = "BUMP",
  CLAP = "CLAP",
  INSPECT = "INSPECT",
  RUN = "RUN",
  TALK = "TALK",
  WALK = "WALK",
  WAVE = "WAVE",
}
export enum ActionState {
  INACTIVE,
  MAP_ACTIVE,
  UI_ACTIVE,
  ENDED,
}
type TactionContext = "action" | "communication" | "reaction";

type Taction = {
  action: ActionName.BUMP;
  communication: ActionName.INSPECT | ActionName.TALK;
  reaction: ActionName.CLAP | ActionName.WAVE;
};

export type Tanimate<T> = (args: {
  name: T;
  onEnd?: () => void; 
}) => void;

interface IactionContextVar<K extends TactionContext> {
  name: Taction[K];
  animate?: Tanimate<Taction[K]>;
  state: ActionState;
}

export interface IplayerActionVar {
  action: IactionContextVar<"action"> | null;
  communication: IactionContextVar<"communication"> | null;
  reaction: IactionContextVar<"reaction">;
}

export type Tregistered = {
  [C in TactionContext]: Map<string, IactionContextVar<C>>;
};
const registered: Tregistered = {
  action: new Map(),
  communication: new Map(),
  reaction: new Map(),
};

type Tregister = <T extends TactionContext>(args: {
  context: T;
  id: string;
  data: Omit<IactionContextVar<T>, "state">;
}) => void;
export const register: Tregister = ({ context, id, data }) => {
  registered[context].set(id, {
    ...data,
    state: ActionState.INACTIVE, <== TS-ERROR !
  });
};
```

I get an error `type ActionState is not assignable to type 'never'` when trying to register a new action to the appropriate Map in my **registered** object.

The underlying ts error is

> [tsserver 2345] [E] Argument of type 'IactionContextVar' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'never'.   The intersection
> 'IactionContextVar<"action"> & IactionContextVar<"communication"> &
> IactionContextVar<"reaction">' was reduced to 'never' because property
> 'name' has conflicting types in some constituents.

I'm trying to type the calls to register so that the proper context is used depending on the action (if registering a "TALK", it must go to the "communication" context).

The only way I've found is to copy-paste the same function over 3 times

```
type Tregister <T extends TactionContext>= (args: {
  context: T;
  id: string;
  data: Omit<IactionContextVar<T>, "state">;
}) => void;
export const registerAction: Tregister<"action"> = ({ context, id, data }) => {
  registered[context].set(id, {
    ...data,
    state: ActionState.INACTIVE,
  });
};
export const registerCommunication: Tregister<"communication"> = ({ context, id, data }) => {
  registered[context].set(id, {
    ...data,
    state: ActionState.INACTIVE,
  });
}
export const registerReaction: Tregister<"reaction"> = ({context, id, data}) => {
  registered[context].set(id, {
    ...data,
    state: ActionState.INACTIVE,
  });
};
```

I'd like typescript to understand that there are 3 different scenarios here, and not lump the different types together in an intersection. How would that be possible ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be a solution for you.  The key change is to declare `name: keyof Taction` instead of using a generic in that case.

```
enum ActionName {
  BUMP = "BUMP",
  CLAP = "CLAP",
  INSPECT = "INSPECT",
  RUN = "RUN",
  TALK = "TALK",
  WALK = "WALK",
  WAVE = "WAVE",
}
export enum ActionState {
  INACTIVE,
  MAP_ACTIVE,
  UI_ACTIVE,
  ENDED,
}
type TactionContext = "action" | "communication" | "reaction";

type Taction = {
  action: ActionName.BUMP;
  communication: ActionName.INSPECT | ActionName.TALK;
  reaction: ActionName.CLAP | ActionName.WAVE;
};

interface IactionContextVar {
  name: keyof Taction;
  state: ActionState;
}

export interface IplayerActionVar {
  action: IactionContextVar | null;
  communication: IactionContextVar | null;
  reaction: IactionContextVar;
}

export type Tregistered = {
  [C in TactionContext]: Map<string, IactionContextVar>;
};
const registered: Tregistered = {
  action: new Map(),
  communication: new Map(),
  reaction: new Map(),
};

type Tregister = <T extends TactionContext>(args: {
  context: T;
  id: string;
  data: Omit<IactionContextVar, "state">;
}) => void;
export const register: Tregister = ({ context, id, data }) => {
  registered[context].set(id, {
    ...data,
    state: ActionState.INACTIVE
  });
};
```

You can try it out in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxgFwJYHsQDkCGFhQN4BQUUAQgKoCyAClALxQBE51DANEVAMIAyMN9DHnzYcAkugDKVAKKcAKnUbipsuSOIAlMukUMt6dVDkxuAaV3GzhgOonzA21fbFbANWm630kQF8CwAA8ABxQAJwQoUEhYRFQQCQRMBFxCYnEYeVF3ZygKPgB9DLks6RyyUULM7I5pdAARaTr2PwQATyDcOUxYtE40ZICIgW7kNAYoAB9GOBQICDAQJDgkuPGphlDgEdWAbgICNo6jbbRFVKgTkAAuGNGMbGAAOmYqPeIZuYWllbQb%20DusDhHsoZPJJrc4oCnpZTG8oJtLn8evcgUIaFN-pCHo8vHsfHsCEgQMlQgAzbq4USXPrEwIIVyYUL4DggB43ADWwFaKFJx2RcIAzolkki7gkksA8ftAiFwlAiSTyXBKUEADaYVrAUKYtAMpnnRFQKnImkDemM8HgVWquEfeaLZZ3G7Gu6mul6y1ga1whHI53U-ruxlS-zBMIRQ6dTYAcyQQq1wAAJmcOABtTjykB812BwYAXRuFEwQQAPELQkTo6wjQHaYM9QA%20PF7GYgIXw4Cx%20ObRM3OQxuMkpMp4iGkDAADuuWLAAoAJQ5O1fR1xG7jqdFoLznK%20p1QdfTrcLgj4-aRowD7uKEsKOmgRMC7NxN2DBszxnRgU3c6ts19uFIL2UDlpWcKJkkmA3AA8hASAICWLrPrm5qhNWDBChKDBNiec50A2UAAG4oIBewyuGUCtu2l4kn21FaooM54BRyHVoB1bgYkUA%20LhtD4ecdE9qmv50nmjwCsACAzmxzLEMQjzyRxmA5MQGEihCaDiskwLoEUJQcNxzZAA)

Edit after question was edited: I wasn't able to get perfect type safety, but adding `animate?: Tanimate<keyof Taction>;` gets close (i.e. you could have two different actions for `name` and `animate`).  So either just "don't do that", or if you can't simply avoid that, then adding a run-time check might be the solution.

```
export type Tanimate<T> = (args: {
  name: T;
  onEnd?: () => void; 
}) => void;

interface IactionContextVar {
  name: keyof Taction;
  animate?: Tanimate<keyof Taction>;
  state: ActionState;
}
```

[Updated TypeScript playground after edit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=33&ssc=2&pln=24&pc=1#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxgFwJYHsQDkCGFhQN4BQUUAQgKoCyAClALxQBE51DANEVAMIAyMN9DHnzYcAkugDKVAKKcAKnUbipsuSOIAlMukUMt6dVDkxuAaV3GzhgOonzA21fbFbANWm630kQF8CwAA8ABxQAJwQoUEhYRFQQCQRMBFxCYnEYeVF3ZygKPgB9DLks6RyyUULM7I5pdAARaTr2PwQATyDcOUxYtE40ZICIgW7kNAYoAB9GOBQICDAQJDgkuPGphlDgEdWAbgICNo6jbbRFVKgTkAAuGNGMbGAAOmYqPeIZuYWllbQb%20DusDhHsoZPJJrc4oCnpZTG8oJtLn8evcgUIaFN-pCHo8vHsfHt-MEwhFDp1MIsIElgAAeOQAPkUAApMKEAOYAZxu5xADxucjhaGkIAAJgB%20G6MgCUdAZADcUEhhTsoAQfNLaHKFUr9kgQMlQgAzbq4USXPp6wIIVws-AcHk4G4Aa2ArRQBuOyLh5KQlOS4uOFKp1OdrvdXWRdLh7MSySRdwSVLx%200CIXCUF1%20qNcBNQQANphWsBQpi0NbQrbiIioKbkeaBlabVNwLnc3CPvNFss7jca3c65ay%20Dm62OAjkT2zf0Byyk4TUyT2p1NqykNGi8BhWcOABtTjpkAevtTwYAXRuFEwQWp0dCutZrGrk4tgzLkdVexmIGj8OAK7Xm2FPll1XfUNy3StxygEBgAAd1yS8pRydsvi7OIbmguCLyCRDRy2SCMPg7DJWaAlSSMYD-0UWlIkGUBhXZQ84n7QY6WZNlOQrKBP3rPk4UVG4bzvOFhSSTAbgAeQgJAEGpXsmOPBtQgfBhoypBg3zVGUoHlRU9hTYkuLQb8KP1IDfxAosmTwQznwQB9FQfETEigTSNU4kz12FbduMtE9HnZYAEEZBzOOIR5wqczAcmIVTYwhNAE2SYF0CKEoODVPEdiAA)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! 
I was trying to keep my example short, and left out an important piece of the interface. I updated it with a key "animate" that also uses the literal.

If using a keyof, is it still possible to type 2 keys of the interface with the same literal value ?

Comment: Well I tried to accommodate the edited question, but I couldn't get it perfect.  I edited my answer to get "pretty close".  If it gets you on your way, please accept the answer or perhaps up-vote if you feel you can't accept it.